# Deprecated: 'sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:' in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

I have my own class to make http calls but now in iOS9 this method is deprecated:

`[NSURLConnetion sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`

I'm trying to test the new one
`[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]`

but Xcode give an error because it doesn't found this method.

Xcode compiler warning with deprecated line:

```
 'sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h
```

Error with new method:

```
No known class method for selector 'dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:'
```

Method:

```
-(void)placeGetRequest:(NSString *)action withHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))ourBlock {

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", URL_API, action];


    NSURL *urlUsers = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlUsers];

    //[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:ourBlock];
    [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:ourBlock];
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` is an instance method, not a class method. You have to either configure a new session or use the shared one:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:ourBlock] resume];
```

Comment: It runs :) But, is it necessary or recommended to configure a specific session?

Comment: @EnriMR Depends on your case. Since you used `NSURLConnection` until now, you can use the shared session. Apple uses it internally for `NSURLConnection` since iOS 7.

Comment: Could you give more detail about which class to use to configure a new session?

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas Take a look at the documentation. You create a session using the factory method, by providing a delegate and a session configuration object. Implement the delegate to be notified of events, and handle things like authentication challenges.

Comment: Don't forget to call [task resume]

Answer (score 14):

```
[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error)
 {
 // Block Body 
 }];
```

Comment: didn't you just copied Leo Natan's answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **AFNetworking** library, you can use a session and then set up to support requests in the background. Using this approach I solved two problems:

1) AFNetworking method is not deprecated

2) the request processing will be done even if the application between the state background

I hope it helps to similar problems. This is an alternative.

```
-(void) pingSomeWebSite {

    NSString* url = URL_WEBSITE; // defines your URL to PING

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    request.timeoutInterval = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT; // defines your time in seconds

    NSTimeInterval  today = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", today];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:identifier];
    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL; // interval max to background 

    __block AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc]
                                            initWithSessionConfiguration:
                                            sessionConfig];

    NSURLSessionTask *checkTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                             completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"- Ping to - %@", URL_WEBSITE);

        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){

            [manager invalidateSessionCancelingTasks:YES];

            // LOGIC FOR RESPONSE CODE HERE 
        });
    }];

    [checkTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in

// Code

}
task.resume()
```